# docker run cannot find name flag argument

Tags: ssh, docker, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have recently setup a Rstudio application on Google compute container engine using Docker and the Rocker/rstudio package. Now I want to start my saved container with a name using the following ssh command line:

```
sudo docker -d -p 8787:8787 --name samplename user/laatste
```

which returns the following error

```
flag provided but not defined: --name
```

I have tried with and without quotes, equal signs, double and single hyphens, before, between and after the other flags and arguments, but the same error keeps returning.

version information:

```
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.1
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

The reason I want to name the container is that I want to run standard (static) startup and shutdown scripts with the Google compute instance to automatically save and load changes made in R. The container name is used for identifying the container to be saved. Any other solution for this is also very welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you wanted to do:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8787:8787 --name samplename user/laatste
```

You forgot to specify command (run) here.

Comment: Thanks!, works like a charm, I cant believe I spend pretty much half a morning on this